# Guestlist seating plan concurrency problem

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I need help solving what I guess it is a concurrency problem.

I'm implementing a system (api + mysql db) to manage a guest list for a venue. The rules are the following:
1- There are tables each one with a given capacity (this is given)
2- Guests can bring an group of accompanying friends
3- Guests can make requests to be seated in a certain table with their friends

I'm now implementing the api endpoint to add the guests to the seating plan. The endpoint will receive the guests name, required table id and the number of accompanying friends. Obviously for each request I need to check if the required table still has the capacity to seat the guest and his friends, but what happens if I have 2 requests to the same table which does not have the capacity to seat all the people from both groups? It can happen that both requests arrive at the same time, the check the endpoint does to ensure the table still has the capacity is positive because it was done before any of the requests actually updated the table that has the seating plan, which is afterwards done since the checks passed and the capacity is exceeded without any error being thrown.

Thanks for any help

No ideas yet, the best case scenario in my idea would be if there was some kind of database constraint that would allow me to implement the capacity check

Comment: Mysql does provide concurrency control: it is called locking. However, database loxks are not meant to be held for more than a few seconds and selecting seats may take longer than that. So, you may have to do this on application level using locking or queuing

Comment: @Shadow, no need to hold a lock for more than a fraction of a second. Picking any seat _immediately_ puts it on a temporary hold (takes a fraction of a second) that will automatically expire (takes a fraction of a second) if the purchase is not finalized (takes a fraction of a second) within, say, five minutes of placing the hold. Choosing additional seats adds each to the same _hold set_ \* so that all of the holds expire in the same instant if not purchased before the timeout. [\* I just made up, "hold set." I'm not a database person. I don't know what the real database people call it.]

Comment: @daniel, I said, "automatically expire" above, but I would _not_ implement it by setting a timer. What happens if the server where the timer is ticking crashes? What I would do instead is mark the seat as "on hold _until time T._" Then, if some new customer is searching for available seats, and they see one that's been on hold for longer than it's expiration date, then the _new_ customer can change it back to "available." Meanwhile, if the original customer has finally found his wallet, and come back to their computer, but too late! then their transaction will fail because they lost the seats.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you described an example of application-level locking that I referred to in my comment...